# Sum column but include only cells that have matching criteria in multiple columns in same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with four columns, call them `A`, `B`, `C`, and `Value`. What I want to do is sum the `Value` column but only include those cells that have a certain criteria matching in columns `A`, `B` and `C`.

An example, in English: SUM the values in the `Value` column that have a value of 6 in column `A`, a value of 10 in column `B` and a value less than 15 in column `C`.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for [`SUMIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B)

Comment: Ah, yes, SUMIFS is exactly what I need - thank you @cybernetic.nomad

Answer (score 0):

Make a table like the attached image in excel.

In B10 put:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,B14,B2:B8)
```

In the B14 put the criteria.

[image: Example Excel File]

Comment: OP is looking for a multi-column match.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing but the multiple criteria were in a single column. In my case, I was using LibreOffice (which has the same syntax but uses `;` instead of `,` as separators).

The solution is to sum multiple [`SUMIF`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

```
=SUMIF(A2:A8,"porshe",B2:B8)+SUMIF(A2:A8,"porshe",B2:B8)+SUMIF(A2:A8,"mazda",B2:B8)
```

If you want the OR operator on the sum.

If you want AND operator you need to use [`SUMIFS`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) that has multiple criteria and ranges.

```
=SUMIF(B2:B8,"porshe",A2:A8,"electric",C2:C8)
```